# Flask HTML Modal Title not aligned correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, bootstrap-modal

so my modal title is not correctly aligned. I'm not sure why to be honest. Maybe something to do with the versions of bootstrap i'm working with. However, I can't change that since will break my entire website so will need to find a work around.

Here is what it looks like currently: [![enter image description here][1]][1]

And here is what it is supposed to look like: [![enter image description here][2]][2]

As you can see the X/close button and title (Message) is not aligned correctly like it is in the second image.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfQMw.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0dUO.png

My code:

```
{% extends "_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal text-center">Add funds into balance</h1><br>
        <div class="form-floating">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" onclick="crypto">USDT-TRX</a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" style="text-align: start;" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Recipient:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Message:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
{% endblock %}
```

my base.html (parent file with bootstrap versions etc):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mysite</title>
    <!-- meta -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <!-- styles -->
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename="styles.css")}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    {% block css %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>

    {% include "navigation.html" %}

    <div class="container">

      <br>

      <!-- messages -->
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
      {% if messages %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {% for category, message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
           {{message}}
           <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}

      <!-- child template -->
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    </div>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% block js %}{% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In BootStraps 3 examples- the `button` element comes before the `h4` element in the `div.modal-header` [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-grid-system)

Comment: @PGHE https://prnt.sc/Gzw3f_tf9I_l did not fix it unfortunately.

Comment: You're also mix and matching your Bootstrap Javascript versions - you've included `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js` at the bottom but also `http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js` in your `head` - check if removing version 5 helps.

Comment: @PGHE That did nothing too unfortunately.